# image textures render with a blur even though i have them set to 'closest' in the nodes

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, blur

when i render, the image textures(face and image on tshirt) render with a blur but i have them set to closest so they should be clear. this doesnt usually happen and im not doing anything particularly different unless i accidently pressed something without realising. i have the render dimensions pretty low(360x360) and everything else renders ok with no blur.[image] im in cycles btw

Comment: update- i just appended everything to a new file and its g now so no need to worry. not really a proper solution so if someone still want to answer they can